# Make postfix use the 'from' email address for X-Postfix-Sender

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to set up postfix as a relay for Amazon SES. SES will only allow emails to be sent from particular (verified) email addresses. This part works. Now I need to integrate with PHP.

What I need is to support multiple verified email addresses, e.g. site1@example.com, site2@example.com. I need postfix to set the `X-Postfix-Sender` header to the value of the 'From' header I pass into the mail() call. Unfortunately it sets `X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; ubuntu@ip-10-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal` instead.

I'm sending emails using:

```
mail('test@example.com', 'PHP test', 'Test message from PHP at ' . $time, "From: site1@example.com");
```

In the logs I get a refusal from SES: "Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified."

php.ini contains `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t` but this doesn't seem to make much difference.

How can I make postfix set the `X-Postfix-Sender` header to the value of the 'From' header?

========================== ANSWER ==========================

I can do what I want by using the `additional_parameters` option of PHP's mail() method:

```
mail('test@example.com', 'PHP test', 'Test message from PHP at ' . $time, '', "-f site1@example.com");
```

This passes the '-f' flag and a from address to sendmail.

Comment: Why not set the _X-Postfix-Sender_ in PHP's mail() function? Using the ini value _sendmail_path_  would also be an option.

Comment: doesn't work. postfix adds it's own anyway that overrides it (appears higher in the message so Amazon read that instead). also sendmail_path won't let me dynamically set the from address.

Comment: Here's the answer (why bother even to quote this) : http://semi-legitimate.com/blog/item/how-to-rewrite-outgoing-address-in-postfix

Answer (score 1):

You might use the `smtp_generic_maps` parameter in postfix main configuration file - `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to rewrite your local domain to a globally valid domain. Check the following links for the details - [smtp_generic_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_generic_maps) and [how to set it up](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html).

-Add the smtp_generic_maps entry to /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
  smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

-Create the /etc/postfix/generic file with the following contents

```
 ubuntu@ip-10-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal   ubuntu@example.com
```

Make sure to restart postfix:

```
 systemctl restart postfix
```

Comment: I'm hosting multiple domains, so this may not work since I need the PHP code to determine which 'From' envelope address is set.

Comment: you can use a unique user in your php code so that postfix will rewrite only that user's domain.